# Does this number have an expression as square root or log of something

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, golden-ratio

If this ends up being a ridiculous question I will delete it.  Forgive me if this is ridiculous but this number has me stumped.

$$1.52360679774998$$

The continued fraction calculator gives $1, 1, 1, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11 ...$ which makes me think this number should have a nice expression as a root or log of something or be related to some special number like $\phi$.  But I've been unable to tease out any such expression.  I appreciate it if someone has more insight into this.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.52360679774998) gives possible closed form solutions, if that's what you're looking for. (e.g., $$ \frac{1}{10}\left(13+\sqrt{5}\right) $$)

Comment: What are the rest of the digits? Where did this number come from?

Comment: @EnviousPage: Snap.  I knew it had something to do with $\phi$. If you had posted this as an answer the check would have gone to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we assume that the continued fraction expansion that you quoted continues in that pattern forever, we can do the calculation by hand. For let $x$ be the value of the continued fraction $\langle 0;11,11,11,\dots\rangle$.  Then $x=\dfrac{1}{11+x}$. This gives a quadratic equation with positive root $\dfrac{5\sqrt{5}-9}{2}$.

Now we can claw our way to the top. For example, $\langle 0;10,11,11,11,\dots\rangle=\dfrac{1}{10+x}=\dfrac{2}{5\sqrt{5}+9}$. Continue, resisting the urge to rationalize the denominator. At the end we get $\dfrac{5\sqrt{5}+31}{10\sqrt{5}+20}$. Finally, rationalize the denominator. We get $\dfrac{13+\sqrt{5}}{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: $$\frac{13+\sqrt{5}}{10} \approx 1.52360679774997896964091736687...$$

(I got the result using the Inverse Symbolic Calculator: http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au )

Comment: I get a 404 with your link, but deleting advancedCalc gets me there

Comment: Try [this link](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced).

Answer (score 1):

As I had said in the comments, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.52360679774998) gives multiple closed form solutions for numbers. The first three are:

$$ \frac{1}{10}\left(13+\sqrt{5}\right), \quad \frac{\Phi+7}{5}, \quad \frac{1}{5\Phi}+\frac{6}{5} $$

where $\Phi$ is the [golden ratio conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Golden_ratio_conjugate).